# Getting a Particular Binary Package from A Source Package?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

(Sorry if the title is worded incorrectly - I am a newbie in this domain, so please correct me wherever I am wrong)

From https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/amd64/hdf5, I am trying to get the package **libhdf5-serial-dev**. However, the link says, "The following binary packages are built from this source package" - which I take to mean that the given source package **hdf5_1.10.0-patch1+docs.orig.tar.gz** can be used to get any of the listed binary packages.

Now, I am a Unix newbie, so forgive me if I get this wrong, but what I understand is that I can somehow tailor my "build" such that I get my desired **libhdf5-serial-dev** package. Indeed, when I run `./configure`,`make` and `make install` right now, I see that it creates the directory `hdf5`, which does not have the files that **libhdf5-serial-dev** has. I suppose I want a directory named **libhdf5-serial-dev**? If this is correct, how can I achieve this? If this is incorrect, please tell me how to understand this!

Answer (score 0):

[libhdf5-serial-dev](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libhdf5-serial-dev)
is described as:

> **transitional dummy package**
>
> This package is a transitionnal package from libhdf5-serial-dev to
> libhdf5-dev. It can safely be removed.

The package you really want is `libhdf5-dev`, which should be found in your
standard repository. You may install it using `apt`.

Comment: I don't have apt and I am not able to get it either - since I am on a cluster, I cannot download it. I also don't have sudo privileges. This is why I am trying to build it myself. Do you have any other recommendation?

Comment: Yes, don't bother making libhdf5-serial-dev - it's nothing. Try instead [libhdf5-dev](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libhdf5-dev). But you will have a problem with dependencies. Why don't you create an Ubuntu virtual machine where you're the administrator and can install anything you like?

Comment: I can certainly try that - but do you have a suggested way for doing that if I am operating on a cluster? I cannot download softwares like VirtualBox, I think.

Comment: I suppose also that you can't boot from a USB?

Comment: Unfortunately not. All I have is terminal. The cluster does have Bash, so I have wget, for example, if that helps?

Comment: Your environment is too locked-down for me. You had better talk with the administrators and explain why you need to use `libhdf5-dev`. It seems like only they can do it. Trying to work around their restrictions can get you in deep troubles.